# Two parents with the same child css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am surprised this has not come up before. Often times when I am styling my website, I have two parents with the same type of child, say:

```
form#login-form
```

and

```
form#reset-form
```

And in each of these parents, styling the child:

```
input[type="submit"]
```

I would have to do:

```
form#login-form input[type="submit"], form#reset-form input[type="submit"] {
    width: 14.75em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    border: none;
}
```

Surely, there is an easier way to do this in CSS? If not, I have code such as

```
.sidebar-outer + *:not(:empty), .sidebar-outer + *:empty + *
```

Where `.sidebar-outer` is a parent with two children.

Comment: Can't you simply create a class on the `input` fields?

Comment: @LucasArbex I believe this is redundant

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What's wrong with your selectors?

Comment: Perhaps form input[type="submit"], or use SASS. SASS allows you to use mixins

Comment: @Michael_B If I have a long selector, it would turn into something like:
`.sidebar-outer + *:not(:empty), .sidebar-outer + *:empty + *`

Comment: Selectors are relative to the rest of your CSS code. If you have many rules, then you may need longer selectors and specificity becomes an important issue.

Comment: @Michael_B I have both many rules and long selectors

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick can you make an answer about SASS (I don't know what that is or how to use that)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a common class to all the input fields 
example -

```
<form id = "login-form">
  <input class="common-class" type="submit"/>
</form>
<form id = "reset-form">
  <input class="common-class" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

And under the css class you can have the below -

```
.common-class{
    width: 14.75em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: If there is no better option, I guess this is what I will use.

Comment: What better option would there be? If you need to apply the same styles to each input it makes perfect sense to do it this way.

Comment: @EternalHour Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

SASS is like CSS on steroids. Just search for "SASS CSS". That said, the best practice way to use it is to start using NPM+Webpack ... worth the learning effort. With SASS you can do something like:

```
@mixin myinputbuttonstyles {
width: 14.75em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    border: none;
}

form#login-form, form#reset-form {

input[type="submit"] {
@include myinputbuttonstyles; 
}

}
```

This sample shows 2 features of SASS: nesting and mixins.